# Windows7 and Redhat Linux: How to make computers able to hard shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 2 systems that will be not be accessible to users, and will frequently lose power, one is running windows7, and one is redhat linux. Is there some settings I can do so that they don't require a soft shutdown?  Linux machine is running ext4, and windows ntfs.
Thanks.

Comment: some ups software might do this....that's the only way i've ever dealt with this

Answer (score 1):

I would put them on a small UPS and have the UPS invoke a shutdown when power is lost.

Comment: I can't have a UPS, I need the OS to be able to take it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a UPS you options are quite limited. In windows 7 you can probably tell the OS to reboot in the event of a power outage (I am sure you can do this in Red Linux as well). I wouldn't recommend this as frequent Hard Shutdowns will eventually lead to some sort of file/disk corruption that could be irrepairable....

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're using them for.  If you can make your complete Red Hat solution fit on a DVD, you can boot off that and not even use a hard disk, which makes power outages less of a problem.  This would work if it's a router or firewall, not so much if it's a file server.

Comment: I can't boot off a DVD either.  Do I have to make fs readonly?

Comment: You don't *have* to make the root filesystem read only, but it would certainly increase fault-tolerance.  I gather you don't want to spend much on this?  The other suggestion about a UPS is good (and both boxes could share a UPS).